# Form.CreateGraphics() returns wrong Dpi

Tags: c#, winforms

I have WinForms applications which started to behave strangely after some Windows Update. 
So, I set Font scale settings to **125% (120 Dpi)**. After that application started to shorten text. After investigation I found the cause, method `this.CreateGraphics()` returns `Graphics` object with `DpiX/DpiY == 96` even though in `OnPaint()` `e.Graphics` has `DpiX/DpiY == 120`. How is it possible?

p.s. if I execute `Graphics.FromHwnd` in `OnPaint()`, it still returns 96 Dpi.

p.s2. Dpi virtualization disabled

**Update**

After additional investigation I'm able to reproduce that behavior in a simple application. 
By default application is being run with **Dpi virtualization** (if nothing set in manifest file and `SetProcessDPIAware` wasn't called).

In order to make mess with **Dpi** `SetProcessDPIAware` should be called after Form creation. After that two strange things will happen:

1. `Form.OnPaint` method will have different e.Graphics.DpiX in depends on what control is in focus, e.g., if Forms is being resized `OnPaint` is called and DpiX == 96, if move mouse over any Button `OnPaint` is called with DpiX == 120.
2. `OnPaint` for UserControl always has DpiX == 120, but `this.CreateGraphics()` returns DpiX == 96.

I still don't get why different components have different **Dpi**.

[Change Windows scaling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brnXx.png)

Comment: I don't think setting font scale will change your dpi...

Comment: Getting 96 is pretty normal.  Be sure to declare your app [to be dpiAware correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13228495/17034).

Comment: @HansPassant Not, it not normal. It always used to get correct Dpi until last time. 96 is OK when Dpi virtualization enabled, but with disabled one it should return correct number.

Comment: I don't disagree, but it certainly wasn't obvious from the question that you took care of that.   Getting both 96 and 120, hmya, extraordinary claims do normally require extraordinary evidence.

Comment: So it seems you did not declare it dpiAware correctly.  You must call SetProcessDPIAware() *before* you create any window.  Just do it right, favor the manifest.

Comment: @HansPassant: it clear from my update that SetProcessDPIAware() should be called before create form, but I want to understand why different Dpis appear.